# SQL error in concat with two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I am trying this code. However i am getting a syntax error. What is the correct way?

```
UPDATE Classificacao AS C
SET C.ClassificacaoCPV_id = (
    SELECT CONCAT(
      SELECT ClassificacaoCPV FROM Classificacao, 
      SELECT substring_index(`ClassificacaoCPV_id`,'|',-1) FROM Classificacao)
 )
```

> ERROR: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'SELECT C.ClassificacaoCPV FROM Classificacao,
>   SELECT substring_index(`Class' at line 4

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23, question updated.

Comment: You have no filters on the subquery. Is that intentional? You are likely getting more than one result back when MySQL wants just one result.

Comment: The braces not matched!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran, you are right, but the problem remains.

Comment: Can you edit your post with some sample data from the table and then the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can pull from this is that you want to create an ClassificatiocaoCPV_id that is the concatenation of ClassificacaoCPV and a portion of the existing ClassificatiocaoCPV_id.

```
UPDATE Classificacao
   SET ClassificacaoCPV_id = 
          CONCAT(ClassificacaoCPV, substring_index(ClassificacaoCPV_id,'|',-1))
```

This is a little dangerous to do on the fly.  Your assumptions will only work once and then you may be out of luck on pulling the `ClassificacaoCPV_id` column again.  A couple of recommendations for you:  1) Run the following query and make sure the results are what you expect before updating the column that you are also pulling data from. 2) Add an additional column such as `ClassificacaoCPV_id_new` for the new ID column instead of updating the column that you are pulling part of the data from.

`select CONCAT(C.ClassificacaoCPV, substring_index(ClassificacaoCPV_id, '|',-1)
 from ClassificacaoCPV`

Remember to measure twice, because you only get to cut once.

Answer (score 0):

You need additional parentheses for subqueries:

```
UPDATE Classificacao AS C
SET C.ClassificacaoCPV_id = (
    SELECT CONCAT(
      (SELECT ClassificacaoCPV FROM Classificaca o), 
      (SELECT substring_index(`ClassificacaoCPV_id`,'|',-1) )
    FROM Classificacao)
 )
```

This assumes that each subquery returns one value.  You might need to use `group_concat()` for this query.

Comment: Same error. I also tried the subqueries, and  they work well separately.